# Graceful exit from Guava Cache call()

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am new to Guava Cache, but I really like this feature so far.
In my implementation I am using Guava Cache together with the call() to load the data that is not existing in the cache. I have a requirement to NOT to populate the Cache in case if something goes wrong in the call() method. I would like to do this in a manner so that the overall application logic flow does not get interrupted. 
Any best-practices as to how this can be done?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to throw an exception. – @Louis Wasserman